# How  to stop reminder in alarm

Tags: android

I have created the reminder in my application. but whenever i click the reminder button it starts playing continuously.but i want after some time stop the alarm(like after 10 or 20 secs). can you please help me for this.

My Code section

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, date.getMonth());
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, date.getYear());             
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, date.getDay());
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, date.getHours());
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, date.getMinutes() + 5);
```

Comment: can you explain with code. i could not understand what you are telling.please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code to stop alarm. This code is used to cancel an alarm time.

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
   alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```